# Attempted to call the default export of C:\Users\Teyllay\Desktop\ss.lv\frontend\src\app\apollo.ts from the server but it's on the client

Tags: next.js, routes, graphql, apollo

so problem is i want to query user info when entering user page like website/user/1
but when i want enter page i'm getting error, i think it's from apollo, so is there a way to fix this? what i did wrong?

apollo.ts:

```
"use client";
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

const createApolloClient = () => {
  return new ApolloClient({
    uri: "http://localhost:8000/",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
};

export default createApolloClient;
```

layouts.tsx:

```
import "./globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import createApolloClient from "./apollo";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });
const client = createApolloClient();

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
      </html>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
```

user/[userId]/page.tsx:

```
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { GET_USER } from "@/graphql/user";

export default function Page({ params }: { params: { userId: string } }) {
  const userId = parseInt(params.userId);
  if (isNaN(userId)) {
    return <h1>user not found</h1>;
  }

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_USER, {
    variables: { id: userId },
  });

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;

  const { getUser: user } = data;

  console.log(user);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>
        user: {user.name} {user.surname}
      </h1>
      <h1>advert:</h1>
      {user.adverts.map((advert: any) => (
        <li key={advert.id}>
          {advert.location}, {advert.price}
        </li>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

get_user query:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const GET_USER = gql`
  query GetUser($id: Int!) {
    getUser(id: $id) {
      phone
      email
      name
      surname
      adverts {
        id
        location
        price
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

i searched some info on web but i didn`t find solution

Answer (score 0):

Your layout file is a server component, and your `apollo.ts` is marked a client file, so you cannot call that `createApolloClient` function from the layout.

In this case, that's really good: if you were to create your client like that in a server component's module scope, that client would be shared between all your users, potentially leaking secret data.

Please use the official Apollo Client package for Next.js, that will avoid errors such as that.

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client-nextjs